# Comic Book about Jupiter and time travel

Tags: comics, identification-request

I'm trying to find out the name of a comic book I read as a kid, probably in the 80s.

The story was about an astronaut who is caught in a jupiter storm and is transported to another time. It meets a very technologically backward population (similar to barbarians) and in this region there is a giant wall.
On the other side of this wall there is a vast ocean.

I remember that there was at least a second book with the continuation of the story.

The book was in Portuguese but I think it must have existed in other countries.

Can someone help me identify the book?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Good description - it seems distinctive enough that hopefully someone will know it or be able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

It is the Storm collection (draw by Don Lawrence).

Luckily, I found the first one selling at a flea market.

The books I read as a child were:

- The Deep World - (De Diepe Wereld) (1978) (written by Philip 'Saul' Dunn) (PT - O Mundo das Profundesas) and
- The Last Fighter - (De Laatste Vechter) (1979) (written by Martin Lodewijk) (PT - O Último Campeão)

Wiki:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storm_(Don_Lawrence)